# Dynamically encrypting configuration variables and placing them in specific folders

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have a configuration file that contains a list of  string variables that the user is required to change to suit their environment:

Configuration file example:

```
# first_file.yml

value_one: <UPDATE>
value_two: <UPDATE>

# second_file.yml

value_one: <UPDATE>
value_two: <UPDATE>
```

Once the user has changed the UPDATE value, I want to be able to use vault to encrypt each variable before copying the encrypted variable to a file specified in the comment, with the desired out below:

```
# first_file.yml

value_one: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      30663734346135353432323531336536636566643739656332613031636630383237666636366630
      6164633835363766666535656438306534343565636434330a626239396536373032373866353861
      37376665313438363561323262393337313266613237313065396338376438313737393234303434
      3035326633616339340a346164646366623932313261613662633938356662373438643831643830
      3432

value_two: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256...
```

I am unsure how to best approach this problem, with the main challenge being how to:

1. Encrypt each variable successfully, without encrypting the entire file
2. Copy the encrypted variable over to a specified file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just threw this together, but it works for your case, preserving structure and indents:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=; while read line; do
  # read key and value from line
  key=$( echo "${line}" | cut -d: -f1 )
  value=$( echo "${line}" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '\n' )

  # Get spaces to indent
  indent=$( echo "${key}" | grep -o '^ *' )

  # if value is not empty... 
  if [ -n "$value" ]; then
    # Encrypt value and indent
    cval=$( echo -n "${value## }" | sed -e "s/^'//" -e "s/'$//" | ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file ~/.ssh/vault_key.txt | sed "s/^ / ${indent}/")
  fi

  # if key is not empty...
  if [ -n "$key" ]; then
    echo -n "${key}: ${cval}"
  fi
  # End the line
  echo
  # unset cval
  unset cval
done < /dev/stdin
```

Name it `encrypt_values.sh`, run `chmod +x encrypt_values.sh`, then you can run it with

```
cat {input-file} | ./encrypt_values.sh > {output_file}
```

If you have some bizzare structure, run the file through `yq` first to clean it up:

```
yq r {imput-file} | ./encrypt_values.sh > {output_file}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to make some minor changes to suit my file structure, but it works as expected. I cannot fathom how someone can get so proficient in BASH to through something together so fast. It's a special skill.